# Can a abstract class have a method with a return type of another abstract class?

Tags: flutter, dart

My flutter/dart app uses the Provider package with various authentication services such as Google, Apple, Firebase, etc. I want my abstract classes to provide more direction for the various implementations, like this:

```
abstract class AuthService{
    Future<User> signIn();
}

abstract class User{}
```

In reality, I have to implement it as:

```
abstract class AuthService{
    Future<dynamic> signIn();
}
```

because my specific implementations of AuthService won't return a User, but FirebaseUser or AppleUser. Is there a way to have the return type specified as some kind of implementation of my abstract User class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really any different from returning any kind of abstract base class; construct an instance of a concrete class and return it.

```dart
abstract class AuthService{
    Future<User> signIn();
}

abstract class User{}

class FirebaseUser extends User {}

class FirebaseAuthService extends AuthService {
  @override
  Future<User> signIn() {
    return Future.value(FirebaseUser());
  }
}
```

Comment: This was the behavior that I was expecting, but the compiler wasn't accepting it. It turns out that FirebaseUser is a specific class in a firebase package. My implementation that extended from User was MyFirebaseUser. I confused the two.

Answer (score 0):

```
abstract class AuthService<T>{
    Future<T> signIn();
}

class ExampleAuthService extends AuthService<FirebaseUser> {
  @override
  Future<FirebaseUser> signIn() {
    throw UnimplementedError();
  }

}
```

Comment: While it’s acceptable to provide code-only answers, it’s often more useful for the community if you can also provide an explanation of the code and help people understand _why_ it addresses the problem. That can reduce the number of follow-up questions, and  help new developers understand the underlying concepts. Would you mind updating your question with additional detail?